# How to respond to an event after loading a hyperlink page?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I wonder is it possible to respond to an event after the client click the hyperlink and the hyperlink is loaded? Which that event can use properties in the hyperlink(i.e. id, class...etc)?

For example, page_A have a hyperlink

```
<a href="page_B" onclick="some_func">link</a>
```

But since some_func need to use some properties in page_B, let say page_B have this line

```
<p id="a">hello world</p>
```

and some_func want to do something with it(e.g. `document.getElementById("a")`), how can I first load the hyperlink(page_B) then run some_func?

Comment: if redirect another page, how can possible to run previous page client side js file??

Comment: Both page have similar content, it's like view rendering, for example, that p tag on page_B is the only extra thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the localStorage to save the name of the function that you want to execute on the second page, and call it once it loads.

The code would be like this:

**JS**

```
// a sample function to be called
function myFunc() {
    alert("Called from previous page!");
}

// save the name of the function in the local storage
function saveForLater(func) {
    localStorage.setItem("func", func);
}

// if the function exists
if (localStorage.func) {
    // call it (not using the evil eval)
    window[localStorage.func]();
    // remove it from the storage so the next page doesn't execute it
    localStorage.removeItem("func");
}
```

**HTML** (just for testing)

```
<a href="test2.html" onclick="saveForLater('myFunc')">Go to Page 2</a><br/>
<a href="test2.html">Go to Page 2 (not saving function)</a>
```

Notice: as this code runs on the client's side, it is subject to be changed by the user, so you must be careful on how to proceed and execute the "saved" function, or you may find yourself with a security problem.